# nfs daemon doesn't listen 2049 port

Tags: debian, rpc, nfs4

I have some problem with nfs. Looks like its doesn't listen 2049 port on client.
Both client and server has Debian linux.

```
serv$ rpcinfo -p
    program vers proto   port
    100000    2   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   udp    111  portmapper
    100024    1   udp  59336  status
    100024    1   tcp  51481  status
    100003    2   udp   2049  nfs
    100003    3   udp   2049  nfs
    100003    4   udp   2049  nfs
    100021    1   udp  58328  nlockmgr
    100021    3   udp  58328  nlockmgr
    100021    4   udp  58328  nlockmgr
    100003    2   tcp   2049  nfs
    100003    3   tcp   2049  nfs
    100003    4   tcp   2049  nfs
    100021    1   tcp  58936  nlockmgr
    100021    3   tcp  58936  nlockmgr
    100021    4   tcp  58936  nlockmgr
    100005    1   udp  52660  mountd
    100005    1   tcp  44121  mountd
    100005    2   udp  52660  mountd
    100005    2   tcp  44121  mountd
    100005    3   udp  52660  mountd
    100005    3   tcp  44121  mountd
```

But there is no 2049 port on client:

```
client$ rpcinfo -p
    program vers proto   port
    100000    2   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   udp    111  portmapper
    100024    1   udp  36256  status
    100024    1   tcp  55654  status
```

I checked nfs-common and it said "everything is ok":

```
client$  sudo /etc/init.d/nfs-common status
    all daemons running
```

Could you help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perfectly normal. It is not supposed to listen on port 2049 on the client. As long as the NFS server is listening on port 2049, the client will pick a high port number to connect to the server on port 2049. Simply try to export a directory on the server, and try to mount it on the client. There is no need for the client to listen on port 2049.

Comment: Thank you for quick response! I couldn't mount on client, and thought that was a port problem.
My configs: 
on server /etc/exports:

    /var/tiles         <client_ip>(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
on clien /etc/fstab:
    <server_ip>:/var/tiles        /var/tiles      nfs     rw,sync,hard,intr       0       0
Maybe I miss something, because nfs doesn't mount on client:
    $ sudo mount /var/tiles/
    mount.nfs: Connection timed out
Could you please give some advice?

Comment: Please specify the nfs server IP address when you run the mount command, example  - `mount -t nfs 192.168.1.1:/var/tiles /var/times`. The first directory path is on the server, while second one is a local mount point, you can change it to any local dir path.

Comment: Thanks, but direct command doesn't help, same error: "mount.nfs: Connection timed out". Also restarted nfs-common and portmap on both servers, but still no effect. Looks like I have some mistakes in configs, so should go deeper :)